# How to assign multiple LINQ Include() statements to a variable for code re-use?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I would like to store a set of `.include()` statements in a variable since I need to use the same `includes` in multiple locations. So in an attempt to prevent code duplication, here is what I am asking:

For example, take this following query where I eager load several related entities:

```
var record = await db.DisplacementDamageRecords
        .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionRadiationPartsLead)
        .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionInstruments)
                .ThenInclude(mi => mi.Instrument)
        .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionInstruments)
                .ThenInclude(mi => mi.CognitiveEngineer)
        .Include(tr => tr.ProcurementPart)
            .ThenInclude(pp => pp.Part)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(tr => tr.Id == form.Id);
```

It would be useful to extract the `includes` like so:

```
var testRecordIncludes = 
        .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionRadiationPartsLead)
        .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionInstruments)
                .ThenInclude(mi => mi.Instrument)
        .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
            .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionInstruments)
                .ThenInclude(mi => mi.CognitiveEngineer)
        .Include(tr => tr.ProcurementPart)
            .ThenInclude(pp => pp.Part)
```

So that I could then use this variable like so:

```
var record = await db.DisplacementDamageRecords
         .testRecordIncludes()
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(tr => tr.Id == form.Id);
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an extension method like this:

```
 public static class DbExtensions
 {
     public static IQueryable<DisplacementDamageRecord> TestRecordIncludes(this IQueryable<DisplacementDamageRecord> records)
     {
         return records
                  .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
                      .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionRadiationPartsLead)
                  .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
                      .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionInstruments)
                          .ThenInclude(mi => mi.Instrument)
                   .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
                      .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionInstruments)
                          .ThenInclude(mi => mi.CognitiveEngineer)
                   .Include(tr => tr.ProcurementPart)
                      .ThenInclude(pp => pp.Part);
     }
 }
```

Then you can call it as you suggested:

```
var record = await db.DisplacementDamageRecords
         .TestRecordIncludes()
         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(tr => tr.Id == form.Id);
```

Edit:

In the comments you suggested that you have an inheritance where you have a a base class `TestRecord` and 2 subclasses: `DisplacementDamageRecord` and `TestRecord`. All the includes are based on the base class and you would like the extension method to work with the subclasses.

You can do this using a generic constraint. The updated version would be:

```
public static class DbExtensions
 {
     public static IQueryable<T> TestRecordIncludes<T>(this IQueryable<T> records) where T : TestRecord
     {
         return records
                  .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
                      .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionRadiationPartsLead)
                  .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
                      .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionInstruments)
                          .ThenInclude(mi => mi.Instrument)
                   .Include(tr => tr.Mission)
                      .ThenInclude(m => m.MissionInstruments)
                          .ThenInclude(mi => mi.CognitiveEngineer)
                   .Include(tr => tr.ProcurementPart)
                      .ThenInclude(pp => pp.Part);
     }
 }
```

Comment: do you know if it's possible to allow different types as well? for example, I will be using this on `DynamitronRecord` type as well. The includes you see here are all inherited from a base class of `TestRecord`. So this should work if we change your extension to type `TestRecord` correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. You could define multiple extension methods, you could define one per each reusable scenario that you have.

Comment: So in your example, we are defining a type of `IQueryable<DisplacementDamageRecord>`. This Type (DisplacementDamageRecord) inherits from a base class of `TestRecord`. All those `includes` you see are members of my `TestRecord` class. I have another `TestRecord` sub class called `DynamitronRecord` that I would like to use this extension method for. So theoretically, if we define the extension method as `IQueryable<TestRecord>`, then it should work for my subclasses still correct? I can test shortly, just wanted to confirm

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution for what you mentioned

Comment: I had to add the generic to TestRecordIncludes<T>, but other than that, this is what I needed thank you! Once updated I'll mark as correct

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest creating an extension method more generic and call it on your subclasses as needed or keep on your base class the navigation properties that your subclasses should have by default as an array of nav properties.

This extension method takes 2 parameters, 1 is a list of navigation properties to be included on the query and the other is `includeAllRecords`

```
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(string[] includeNavProp = null, bool includeAllRecords = false)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = includeAllRecords ? TableNoTracking.IgnoreQueryFilters() : Table;

        if (includeNavProp != null)
        {
            query = includeNavProp.Aggregate(query, (current, includePath) => current.Include(includePath));
        }

        return query;
    }
```

`includeAllRecords` is used in case you have some query filters that exclude some rows from the final result. Some applications implement soft deletes, passing this parameter will include or exclude rows that were marked as deleted for example. See the idea below of a QueryFilter

```
public abstract class BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<T> : IEntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        builder.Property(dt => dt.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

        builder.Property(x => x.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.CreatedOn).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.UpdatedBy).HasMaxLength(50).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(x => x.UpdatedOn).IsRequired();

        builder.HasQueryFilter(app => !app.IsDeleted);
    }
}
```

With that said, you can call `GetAll` in this way

```
var ddr = db.DisplacementDamageRecords.GetAll(new []{ 
       "Mission.MissionRadiationPartsLead",
       "Mission.MissionInstruments.Instrument",
       "Mission.MissionInstruments.CognitiveEngineer",
       "Mission.ProcurementPart.Part")
```

Now it is up to you how you group your navigation properties to make them reusable.

Hope this helps